# Error in Python modules import: inconsistencies between what I have in Python and what I see in SQL

Tags: python, sql, python-module

I have an issue I can not solve. I have installed several Python modules (eg pandas, numpy, requests and so on) and they work fine. When I connect to SQL and I want to run a Python script (through SQL) I realize the I do not see all the modules I have installed but something like 95% of them.
To check the package installed i used
`help("modules")` in python and

```
@language = N'Python', 
@script = N'
help("modules")'
```

in SQL.
In my opinion they should return the same list but they do not.
I installed all the packages in the same way, writing in the cmd `pip3 import modulename`.
Anyone has any idea on how to fix this behaviour? I have already tried to uninstall and reinstall the packages I did not see in SQL but it did not work.

Thank you for your time

Comment: sorry, the code in SQL was 
```@language = N'Python', 
@script = N'
help("modules")'```

Comment: edit this in the main question itself!

Comment: SQL is a language, and can't run Python. But the dbms you're using perhaps can. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server and I have found literature that explains how to run a Python script from here and it works fine to me. The only problem I have is when I try to call the specific modules that I find in Python but not in SQL Server